# How to prove $A \times C \subseteq B \times D \rightarrow A \subseteq B \land C \subseteq D$ using algebra of classes.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A$ and $C$ are nonempty classes, prove $$A \times C \subseteq B \times D \rightarrow A \subseteq B \land C \subseteq D$$

Comment: What do you mean by 'algebra of classes'?

Comment: @stefan Using the logic operators, $\land , \lor, \rightarrow$ ,etc.

Comment: @bof Thanks, I will correct immediately

Comment: To show $A\subseteq B$ assume $a\in A$ and show $a\in B.$ So let $a\in A$ be given. Since $C\ne\emptyset$ we can choose $c\in C.$ Then $(a,c)\in A\times C\subseteq B\times D$ so $a\in B.$ So much for $A\subseteq B.$ Now can you prove that $C\subseteq D$? By the way, just out of curiosity, which step were you stuck on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very easy: 

Let $x \in A \land y\in C$, for definition of Cartesian product:
$$(x,y) \in A \times C$$
$\rightarrow$For hypothesis:
$$(x,y) \in B \times D$$
$\rightarrow$For definition of Cartesian product
$$x\in B \land y\in D$$
$\rightarrow x \in A \subseteq B\land y \in C \subseteq D $ $\blacksquare$